# Converting string to integer

Tags: vbscript

```
PrinterLabel = Printer + PrinterNumber

If Floors = 1 And (PrinterLabel) > 127 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Invalid Printer11 Selection "    
    Wscript.Quit
End If

If Floors = 2 And PrinterLabel > 220 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Invalid Printerss Selection "    
    Wscript.Quit
End If
```

The problem is that PrinterLabel is a String and I want to convert it to an Int and compare it.

The PrinterLabel is a String that is also a number "218"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The function you need is `CInt`.

ie `CInt(PrinterLabel)`

See [Type Conversion Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) (Visual Basic) on MSDN

**Edit:** Be aware that CInt and its relatives behave differently in VB.net and VBScript.  For example, in VB.net, CInt casts to a 32-bit integer, but in VBScript, CInt casts to a 16-bit integer.  Be on the lookout for potential overflows!

Comment: I tried to convert my Array which stores a string, but i get `Typeconflict: 'CInt'`

Comment: @Black There must be some leading or trailing spaces in numeric string, use `Trim` function to remove them and then cast to a 16-bit integer using `CInt`.